# Is a Retainer actually less useful than the corresponding Service?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, npc

My PC decided to bring his PI in as a Retainer; unfortunately he'd been reading the old core book. In GMC

> If a Retainer needs to make a roll, if it’s within her
>   field, double the dot rating and use it as a dice pool. For
>   anything else, use the dot rating as a dice pool.

Previously a Retainer got its own character sheet. Also compare this to the +2 to dice pool for actually paying for the PI Service.

It seems a little out there that a 3-dot Retainer PI might actually be less useful than the PI Service, because the Service gets added to the character's dice pool (or if the character had a high Investigation roll already), while the retainer might just be 3 dice.

Is my understanding correct that, if the player has the Retainer do anything that's not in  the Retainer's field of expertise it's 3 dice (3 dots were purchased) for the dice pool? Can the Retainer grant any kind of bonus to the Merit owner's own dice pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Less useful, more loyal.

First, the answers to your questions:

- Yes, if a Retainer is doing something "outside its field of expertise," you roll its rating in dice alone. However, what's *inside* its field of expertise is negotiable with the Storyteller. Said PI might have some skill with Crafts, Larceny, or Firearms, but not Medicine or Weaponry.
- You could conceivably have the Retainer take a Teamwork action with the Merit owner's PC. (WoD, 134). That would allow the merit owner a bonus.

Now, the question in the title: A Retainer is going to be less skilled than a corresponding Ally or Mentor of equivalent dot rating — the difference is that a Retainer won't ever sell you out and doesn't ask much in return.